# JOIN 2 tables with multiple columns using PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, performance, join

I admit, I am a bit weak in JOIN conditions. I want to get a result set from 2 tables with 4 matching columns.

I have tried the code below, but I am not sure if it's correct or not, as for the moment I have 3-4 records (and the result is correct). But in the future there might be N records, hence I need a more secure and safe query.

The 2 tables are: TABLEA  and  TABLEB

**TABLEA**

```
id|pid|nid|sid|name|
--------------------
1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | test
2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | t2 
3 | 2 | 2 | 4 | t3
```

**TABLEB**

```
id|pid|nid|sid|marked |
-----------------------------
1 | 2 | 2 | 3 |  y
2 | 2 | 2 | 3 |  y
3 | 2 | 2 | 4 |  n
```

**Below is the query I have tried:**

```
SELECT 
    b.marked 
FROM 
    TABLEA AS a
LEFT JOIN 
    TABLEC AS c ON a.id = c.id
LEFT JOIN  
    TABLEB AS b ON ( 
        a.id = b.id
        AND  a.pid = b.pid
        AND  a.nid = b.nid
        AND  a.sid = b.sid  
    )
```

I am getting the expected result, but I am not sure that query above is perfect for larger amount of records.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this

```
SELECT b.marked from TABLEA as a
LEFT JOIN TABLEC as c on a.id = c.id
LEFT JOIN  TABLEB as b1 ON a.id = b1.id
LEFT JOIN  TABLEB as b2 ON a.pid = b2.pid
LEFT JOIN  TABLEB as b3 ON a.nid = b3.nid
LEFT JOIN  TABLEB as b4 ON a.sid = b4.sid
```

Comment: i had tried that to and got same result.. BUT DON'T YOU THINK its longer step and performance will be decrease , if there are N number records

Comment: need fast and better query hence which one is correct and safe in all ways